# Cannot create the generated HTTP client's required return type, since no TypeConverter from ByteBuffer to class java.io.File : Micronaut

Tags: java, rest, http, micronaut, micronaut-client

Below is the server side code for sending file to client as rest response using micronaut.

```
@Get(value = "/downloadFile", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM )
public HttpResponse<File> downloadDocument() throws IOException {

    File sampleDocumentFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("SampleDocument.pdf").getFile());

    return HttpResponse.ok(sampleDocumentFile).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + sampleDocumentFile.getName() + "\"" );
}
```

Below is the client for calling the above endpoint.

```
@Client(value = "/client")
public interface DownloadDocumentClient {

@Get(value = "/downloadDocument", processes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Flowable<File> downloadDocument();

}
```

Tried to retreive file as below :-

```
Flowable<File> fileFlowable = downloadDocumentClient.downloadDocument();
    Maybe<File> fileMaybe = fileFlowable.firstElement();
    return fileMaybe.blockingGet();
```

Getting exception as

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot create
>   the generated HTTP client's required return type, since no
>   TypeConverter from ByteBuffer to class java.io.File is registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send file data using `File` instance because it contains only path and not file content. You can send file content using byte array.

Update the controller in this way:

```java
@Get(value = "/download", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public HttpResponse<byte[]> downloadDocument() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String documentName = "SampleDocument.pdf";
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(documentName).toURI()));
    return HttpResponse.ok(content).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + documentName + "\"");
}
```

Client will be then like this:

```java
@Get(value = "/download", processes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
Flowable<byte[]> downloadDocument();
```

And finally client call:

```java
Flowable<byte[]> fileFlowable = downloadDocumentClient.downloadDocument();
Maybe<byte[]> fileMaybe = fileFlowable.firstElement();
byte[] content = fileMaybe.blockingGet();
```

**Update:**
If you need to save received bytes (file content) into the file on a client machine (container) then you can do that for example like this:

```java
Path targetPath = Files.write(Paths.get("target.pdf"), fileMaybe.blockingGet());
```

And if you really need instance of `File` instead of `Path` for further processing then simply:

```java
File file = targetPath.toFile();
```

Comment: Okay! , eventually I would need a file object after the client call. So how to get it from byte array ?

Comment: I added an example how to deal with that into the answer.

Comment: Thankyou :)
Though I am able to send data using file instance when file is .txt , for which I dont need any typeConvertor as well and everything is working great.

But for .pdf file , same is not working. Also for pdf file I am facing the abv exception that it needs typeconvertor to convert byteBuffer to File.Even on providing a type convertor , it is not able work and a corrupted pdf is getting downloaded.

Why is it working perfectly for .txt file?

Comment: Try to change client from reactive to blocking (remove `Flowable`): `byte[] downloadDocument();` and then call it: `Files.write(Paths.get("target.pdf"), downloadDocumentClient.downloadDocument());`

Comment: You are welcome ;-) Then if you can please accept the answer. Thanks